# How I reopen a window using pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I created several windows using qtgenerator and I use this kind of slot to hide the current window and show other one:

SearchResearchScreen.py

```
class Ui_ResearchMenu(object):

    def setupUi(self, ResearchMenu):
        ...
    def retranslateUi(self, ResearchMenu):
        ...

    def edit_clicked1(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_EditNewResearch()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()
        ResearchMenu.hide()
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(100)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.checkVar)
        self.timer.start()
```

EditresearchScreen.py -

```
class Ui_EditNewResearch(object):

    def setupUi(self, EditNewResearch):
      ...
    def retranslateUi(self, EditNewResearch):
      ...

    def btn_Cancel_clicked(self):
        global status
        status = False
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_ResearchMenu()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()
        EditNewResearch.hide()
```

This works fine when clicking a button, after that, in the second window I'm using the same code to return to the first window but the application crashes. Unless I comment the `.hide()` but then I cannot return to the same window but to open a new one when the old one still exists in the background.

How do I move through different windows without the program crashing?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I tackled this issue by using QTimer. You should use QTimer in first window which will constantly check for any global variable which you will be updating in both the cases.

Create QTimer like this :-

```
def edit_clicked1(self):
    global status
    status = True # This will be your global variable which will check if the window is closed or not
    self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    self.ui = Ui_EditNewResearch()
    self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
    self.window.show()
    ResearchMenu.hide()
    self.timer = QTimer()
    self.timer.setInterval(100)
    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.checkVar)
    self.timer.start()
```

and check for variable like this

```
def checkVar(self):
    global status
    if status == False:
        # Show your hided window here
        self.show()
```

just keep in mind you need to set this `status` variable to False when closing 2nd window.

Comment: Thanks, but it still not working, I create the Qtimer and in the second window i did like this: 

def btn_back_clicked(self):
    global status 
    status = False 
    self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow() 
    self.ui = Ui_ResearchMenu() 
    self.ui.setupUi(self.window) 
    self.window.show() 
    EditNewResearch.hide()

And still when I press the back button the app crashes and python stop working.

Comment: We cannot find the error without seeing the complete code. If you have any git repo then please upload your code sample to it and share it in your question.